# Selenium-Webdriver/RSpec closing window after tests

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec

Running an issue running RSpec and Selenium-Webdriver. Im rolling my own framework and am running into an issue after each test gets ran. My `spec_helper.rb` setup looks like so:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Dir['./spec/support/**/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do
    # Default browser is chrome, otherwise look for ENV variables
    case ENV['browser'] ||= 'chrome'
    when 'chrome'
      @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    when 'firefox'
      @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    end

    # Clear cookies between each example
    @driver.manage.delete_all_cookies   

    # Set up implicit waits
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5

    # Default base_url is set to website, otherwise look for ENV variables
    case ENV['base_url'] ||= 'https:www.website.com' #redacted real website
    when 'local'
      ENV['base_url'] = 'local_url_here'
    when 'development'
      ENV['base_url'] = 'https:www.website.com' #redacted real website
    when 'production'
      ENV['base_url'] = 'prod_url_here'
    end


    # Close browser window after each test
    config.after(:each) do 
      @driver.close
    end

  end
end
```

My actual rspec tests are setup in the format of:

```
Rspec.describe 'something' do
  context 'some context' do
  #multiple it 'stuff' do's
  end
 end
end
```

Which is pretty typical. However the first test will run fine, after the first test each test runs fine but the browser (Chromedriver in this case) closes after each test and gives the error: `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: no such session`.

So I tried:

```
config.after(:all) do 
  @driver.quit
end
```

Instead. This runs the tests all successfully, but I also get n errors at the end of the test (where n = number of total tests) `undefined method`quit' for nil:NilClass`. It also opens a new browser instance for each test (Which I don't want to do).

RSpec seems to close the driver down from what I can tell even without `@driver.quit`. So im really confused what to do here. I don't want a new browser opening every single instance, but I would like the browser to close after each test and open a new one (Or maybe this is a bad idea?, I am deleting cookies, so if it would just switch to a new URL since I am doing a `visit` for each test would work?)

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that happens when you use chrome driver, it automatically closes the browser at the end.

The solution is to, write the following code for driver object

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("goog:chromeOptions" => {detach: true})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

This will stop the chrome browser getting closed at the end.

And I suggest you to use WATIR which is the wrapper around Ruby selenium binding.