# Selenium auto closing window

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to write selenium bot with ruby, but it just close chrome window after loading page. What can i do? Please help

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--disable-translate')

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

driver.navigate.to "https://google.com"
```

Comment: It seems compatibility issue. Please try with downgrade selenium version

Comment: @Muzzamil No,it's not downgrade issue. Please look at my answer.

Comment: Okay I though it is just closing browser in starting in test but OP just navigating a url only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium-Webdriver/RSpec closing window after tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903500/selenium-webdriver-rspec-closing-window-after-tests)

Comment: Read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903500/selenium-webdriver-rspec-closing-window-after-tests/59908290#59908290

Comment: From the description, I think it says the test case didn't run and the window closed. Or your test doesn't have a test case yet?

Comment: @foxiris It ran successfully and window would be closed for Chrome. Please click the link I gave above where I described how to detach the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running just the code above with nothing else after, what you're experiencing makes a lot of sense. It's exiting after it navigates to Google.

Add this to the end, and the window should stay open

```
$stdin.gets
```